# In python 3 how can I select html <A> tag text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is part of my code, how can I select the '3 sold' between the a tag at the bottom. Using beautiful soup.

```
<body>
<div>
<div class="u-flL qtyCntVal vi-bboxrev-posabs vi-bboxrev-dsplinline">
<div class="errorIcon" id="w1-11-_errIcon" style="display: none;"><!-- 
err_qty_icon -->
<img alt="Error icon" class="errorimg" 
src="http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/pics/s.gif"></div><input 
class="qtyInput" id="qtyTextBox" name="quantity" size="4" type="text" 
value="1"> <span class="qtyTxt vi-bboxrev-dsplblk feedbackON" style=""><span 
id="qtySubTxt"><span class="">9 available</span></span> <span class="vi-qty-
vert-algn vi-qty-slash">/</span> <span class="vi-qtyS vi-bboxrev-dsplblk vi-
qty-vert-algn vi-qty-pur-lnk"><a 
href="http://offer.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?
ViewBidsLogin&amp;item=322646576920&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trksid=p2047675.l2564">3 
sold</a></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "this is the search criteria I must use"?

Comment: this "search criteria I must use " it's not so clear, can you explain it better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get contents of <a> tags using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145178/get-contents-of-a-tags-using-python)

Comment: I have edited it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to reach the desired element. Strictly speaking, we should know the context you are working in - the complete HTML of the page and how unique the element attributes and structures are.

That said, here is one way to get to the desired text using a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) based on classes of the `span` elements along the way to the `a`:

```
soup.select_one(".qtyTxt .vi-qtyS > a").get_text()
```

If the link itself would always point to `ebay`, you may additionally check that in the selector:

```
soup.select_one(".qtyTxt .vi-qtyS > a[href*=ebay]").get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of 'a' tag, where text is your complete text:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
>>> span = soup.findAll('a')[0].next
>>> span
u'3 \nsold'
>>> soup.findAll('a')[0]
<a href="http://offer.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?\nViewBidsLogin&amp;item=322646576920&amp;rt=nc&amp;_trksid=p2047675.l2564">3 \nsold</a>
>>>
```